# sql server 2012 stops working on local database edit table

Tags: database, exception, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015

I just migrated to the latest windows 8.1 and Installed Visual studio 2015 CTP and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and every thing works fine, But when I wanna manage the Local Databases, encounter the following error on edit table command in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

I tested the SQL server management studio for the remote databases and everything works fine but I've trouble in local management. please share your experiences, Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from the reality that Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 doesn't work wit SQL server 2012 since it mentioned is compatible with SQL server 2014 as a requirement. I don't know why! perhaps some DLLs are strongly changed.